# JavaScript: Getting an objects property value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wandering if this is possible below:

```
var layers = {};
layers.group3 = new L.MarkerClusterGroup(); //some group of objects 
layers.group3.name = "somestr"; //here i want to give a property name to group3 object. 


function checkLayers(data, t) {

    for (var name in layers) {
         var value = layers[name];
         alert("name: "+name+ " value: "+value);

         if(layers.group3.name == t){
             //do something
         }
    }     
}
```

How can i access the name property for group3. It does not show up in the alert. And I also want to compare the value to parametar "t".

Comment: `for (var name in layers)` only loops over the properties of `layers`. Your `name` property is a property of the `group3` object, not a property of `layers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the `name` property through iteration, you must check if the property name for the iteration is `group3`.  Once you are sure you have the `group3` property you can access the name property.  The `for...in` loop will iterate over every property of an object, when using `in layers` it iterates over all of `layers` properties, since `group3` is a property on `layers` you cannot access the `group3.name` property by simply iterating over the properties in `layers`.

```
for (var name in layers) {
     if(name == "group3" && layers[name].name = t){
         delete layers[name];
     }
}
```

This can be done much simpler without iteration:

```
alert(layers.group3.name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, okay I find the name property of group3 but then once it matches parametar "t" I want to totally remove that object - "group3" - can i achieve this ??

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code.
It works fine:

```
var layers = {};
layers.group3 = {};
layers.group3.name = "somestr"; //here i want to give a property name to group3 object. 


function checkLayers(data, t) {

    for (var name in layers) {
         var value = layers[name];
         console.log("name: ", name , " value: " , value);

         if(layers.group3.name == t){
             console.log(layers.group3.name);
         }
    }     
}
checkLayers('', 'somestr');
```

Results in console:

```
name:  group3  value:  Object {name: "somestr"} 
somestr
```